# Group array by offset

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following array

```
["M", "A", "M", "I", "M", "P"]
```

These represent two individuals' responses to three different questions. I want to be able to group indexes [0, 3], [1, 4] and [2, 5].

In a case where those same six responses might be three individuals response to two different questions. In which case I'd like to be able to group them by indexes [0, 2, 4] and [1, 3, 5].

I'm using Underscore in this project so a vanilla JS or Underscore solution would do the trick!

Comment: Can you post some more examples of what the input is and what you'd like the desired outcome to be?  Have you tried something to get close?

Comment: So show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Also provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()` to build arrays and inside you need indexes from both iterations so you can use `i + (n * j)`

```js
var arr = ["M", "A", "M", "I", "M", "P"]

function group(arr, n) {
  var part = Math.ceil(arr.length / n);
  return Array.from(Array(n), function(e, i) {
    return Array.from(Array(part), function(a, j) {
      return arr[i + (n * j)]
    })
  })
}

console.log(group(arr, 3))
console.log(group(arr, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const array = ["M", "A", "M", "I", "M", "P"];

const group = (arr, n) => [...Array(n)].map(
  (_, i) => arr.filter((_, j) => (j - i) % n === 0)
);

console.log(group(array, 2));
console.log(group(array, 3));
```